# What is the meaning of "Different worlds"?

Tags: plot-explanation, sicario-day-of-the-soldado

In *Sicario Day of the Soldado (2018)*, Matt uses sign language to ask deaf Blandina about her baby:

> Matt: Is the baby deaf?
>
> Blandina: No.

Matt uses sign language to ask deaf Angel about his baby:

> Matt: **Different worlds**?
>
> Angel: **Different worlds**.

What is the meaning of "Different worlds"?

Answer (score 1):

This refers to their difference in perception - the baby can hear and they can't - growing up she will perceive the world in a different way to them

Later in the movie, Matt will talk of "i understand different worlds" - as in his situation, him and his partner could hear, and their child was deaf.